# What are the use of 1 and 0 in last every mongodb $cond?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

What are the meaning of `1`, `0` in the last $cond in mngo db? line 4.

```
single_registration: { $cond: [
     { $and: [
     { $gte: [ "$registration_created", startDateFirst ] },
     { $lte:[ "$registration_created", endDateFirst ] }
   ] }, 1, 0
] },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) array contents is “if, then, else”. So this says “if this condition is true, then `1`, else `0`.”